# AWS MQTT publish

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers, publish

A consult please, I have obtained this erro:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ForbiddenException) when calling the Publish operation: None",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 75, in lambda_handler\n    response = mqtt.publish(topic='iot/mqtttest', qos=1, payload = json.dumps(mqttData))\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

How can I resolve it?.

I thank you in advance.

I am beginner using AWS, I dont have idea where is my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this and able to resolve it by adding `AWSIoTEventsFullAccess`, `AWSIoTDataAccess` and `AWSIoTFullAccess` permissions to the lambda.